# Editing Firebase Data from TablView in another Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have `TableView` with items which I retrieve from Firebase:

```
// retrieving data from Firebase
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    databaseHandle = ref?.child("Users").child(uid).child("LearnedWords").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        var newItems: [Word] = []
        for item in snapshot.children {
            let wordItem = Word(snapshot: item as! DataSnapshot)
            newItems.append(wordItem)
        }
        newItems.sort(by: { $0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedDescending})
        self.words = newItems
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Each items has randomly generated key, like [this](http://i-fotki.info/22/55e569c42e4bd31d2b954180b9971c99059fe5285300138.jpg.html). Also, I've implemented `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt: IndexPath)` for swipe buttons. [This](http://i-fotki.info/22/84b009094fa5546754bc19b58d8c928d059fe5285300491.jpg.html) is my interface and code for that:

```
  // handle swipe icons and actions
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { action, index in

    }
    edit.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, index in

    }
    delete.backgroundColor = .red

    return [delete, edit]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

**The problem:**

By typing on the "Edit" button I want to go to another controller and *change* the values of this item by typing some text in the textFields. First part is easy, but how can I change certain values in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is take say the name or some significant value. Maybe, "Word" in this case. When your adding it adding it like this.

```
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
databaseRef.child("XXXXX").childByAutoID().setValue(values)
```

Instead of `.childByAutoID()`  do `.child("\(WordThatYourSaving)")`

So like this:

```
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
databaseRef.child("XXXXX").child("\(Word)").setValue(values)
```

If you look on Firebase's Documentation on their website then you can see their code.

```
let post = ["word" : "\(updated word)"]
ref.child("XXX").child("\(word)").updateChildValues(post) // word is the string passed from the previous view controller
```

Does that work?

Niall

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nial! I'd figured this out a few hours before you published your answer, but it is correct. All I had to do is to change my Model file, where I also added random string to Firebase like a key-value pair. Than I had to pass data from one ViewController to another via this TableView method:

```
var word: String!
var translation: String!
var exOne: String!
var exTwo: String!
var key: String!

// handle swipe icons and actions
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { action, index in
        self.word = self.words[editActionsForRowAt.row].word
        self.translation = self.words[editActionsForRowAt.row].translation
        self.exOne = self.words[editActionsForRowAt.row].exOne
        self.exTwo = self.words[editActionsForRowAt.row].exTwo
        self.key = self.words[editActionsForRowAt.row].keyRandom
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "edit", sender: self)
    }
    edit.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
...

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

var editContoller: EditController!

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "edit" {
        editContoller = segue.destination as? EditController
        editContoller.wo = word
        editContoller.tran = translation
        editContoller.eO = exOne
        editContoller.eT = exTwo
        editContoller.key = key
    }
}
```

So, in the new ViewController with all this data I was able to change values easily.